# Is there a way to save offline using firebase react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, offlineapps

I just want to ask , I will build app using react native but the app has a feature which allow the user to add and save his recipe offline is that possible using firebase please I want anyone to answer me !
if yes please tell me how

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry, but this question is not very clear. Please try showing what you've tried and point out exactly what you're stuck on. What have you tried so far? Please post the relevant parts of your code where you're getting stuck. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Realm? It is the best mobile database in my experience. We have used SQLite and Firebase in the past but none them could perform like Realm.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) database the `offline` capabiliteis are by default enabled.

> Offline persistence is supported only in Android, iOS, and web apps.

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#web-version-9).

That means you work with the database as of it is a local one. It will sync automaticaly with the server when there is a connection. There are no futher instructions required. Just use it according to the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore). The `offline` is by default integrated into it.

Comment: but I use expo to build the app so is there a solution ?

Comment: Just use the proper package for it. Does this help you further with it? https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/